# Shutting Down a specific crawler of 3 working crawlers in Crawler4j?

Tags: java, web-scraping, web-crawler, crawler4j

i have multiple working crawlers run together

eg.

-crawler 1

-crawler 2

-crawler 3

my question is: **what if i want to shut down crawler number 2 only?**

i imagine that every crawler in crawler4j has a session ID and i can
shut it off while requesting its ID

**HOW CAN I IMPLEMENT THAT ?**

***edit***

> i know how to shut down working crawler but my question is .. if i
>   have crawling system with users and i want each user have its own
>   crawlers and if user x wants to shut down its crawler .so, crawler of
>   user x shut down with out reflecting and shutting down the user y
>   crawler

Comment: https://github.com/dgoiko/crawler4j/commit/0690eb5c02a5d27d31c80c9e56c737d6b86ec4e9

Too lazy to explain in a full answer

Answer (score 1):

you have to wrap your crawler in a `CrawlController` instance:

```java
CrawlController controller = new CrawlController(config,..);
controller.startNonBlocking(BasicCrawler.class, numberOfCrawlers);

Thread.sleep(30 * 1000);
controller.shutdown(); // shutdown crawling
controller.waitUntilFinish();
```

the complete example you will find [here](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j/blob/master/crawler4j-examples/crawler4j-examples-base/src/test/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/examples/shutdown/ControllerWithShutdown.java)

**update**
a sample code, a `User` with an instance of `controller`:

```java
public class UserCreator {
  public User createNewUser() {
    CrawlController controller = new CrawlController(config,..);
    controller.startNonBlocking(BasicCrawler.class, numberOfCrawlers);

    return new User(controller);
  }
}

public class User {
  private CrawlController controller; 

  public User(CrawlController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
  }

  public void shutdownCrawler() {
    controller.shutdown(); // shutdown crawling
    controller.waitUntilFinish();
  }
}
```

Comment: hello @sudipn , i know that but my question was .. if i have crawling system with users and i want earch user have its crawlers and if user x wants to shut down its crawler , it shut down with reflecting and shutting down the user y crawler

Comment: thank you , but does that code affect the other users crawlers?

Comment: no, if you create a new instance of `CrawlController` every time you create a user. check my updated answer.

Comment: do you mean that if i created new instance of CrawlerController each crawler would has unique  session  to shut it down ?

Comment: the crawler(s) for your user is shutdown using the `CrawlController` as it provides an abstraction on the crawler. I guess you do not have to deal with session ids